# How to change Xamarin back button in menu bar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, menubar, xamarin.forms

this is what I have:

[image]

this is what I want to get:

[image]

If there is no pages in navigation stack, then title icon will be in left corner, else there will be back arrow and "Back" text.
I didn't find any options to customize it, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can change arrow to hamburger icon if you use your `MasterPage` within NavigationPage:

```net
Detail = new NavigationPage(masterPage);
```

If you want to hide icon - it only applies to Android. It can be solved with custom renderer (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/):

```net
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer ))]
public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
        actionBar.SetIcon (Resource.Color.Transparent);
    }
}
```

To change icon, just change project files:

- YourProject/Resources/drawable/icon.png
- YourProject/Resources/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
- YourProject/Resources/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
- YourProject/Resources/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png

or on your `MasterDetailPage` set `Icon` property to another resource.

Answer (score 0):

use the static method SetTitleIcon on the NavigationPage object.