# Xamarin Forms Master Details Page change back button to hamburger menu

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hamburger-menu

I have a xamarin forms app that has the main content as a master details control. The problem im having is that i cant get the hamburger icon to show up when it's deployed to android.

[image]

On the left you have the app deployed in the android simulator and on the right side it's deployed in the iOS simulator. On iOS im getting the Hamburger menu appearing in the top left of the toolbar as expected but i dont get the same on android.

Any ideas on how i get this to come up on android?

Comment: Perhaps this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541603/how-to-change-xamarin-back-button-in-menu-bar

Answer (score 0):

James Montemagno from Xamarin team has instructions to change the master details page icons here
http://motzcod.es/post/115523285992/material-design-theming-for-xamarinforms-android